# jQuery prop taking long time to set selected for all elements of multiselect

Tags: jquery, html

I have about 74000 options under HTML multi-select (Listbox). I want to select all and deselect all at client side using jquery.
I am using following code

```
$("#SearchPublisherCID option").prop("selected", true);
```

But it takes so much time to select all options. about 5 to 7 minutes.
Is there any other options which can do it bit faster.

Comment: *Are there any options to make it faster*:  Yes, don't use such a ridiculous amount of options on a webpage.  Use a better UX with search/filter/paging.

Comment: You can use a context selector which perform better `$("option", "#SearchPublisherCID").prop("selected", true);` Also - if you're selecting a direct child (if `#SearchPublisherCID` represent a select element), then you can improve the selector by doing `$("> option", "#SearchPublisherCID").prop("selected", true);` (note the `>`)

Comment: You may benefit from reading this [UI.se] question, and its answers: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31738/what-is-the-maximum-recommended-number-of-item-to-put-in-a-drop-down-list#